# Octave: how to specify arguments for mkoctfile

Tags: octave, mex

Im am using octave under windows (native) and try to compile a c++ program into a mex file and link some libraries to it:

```
% compile for octave
cmd = sprintf("mex main.cpp -I\"%s\\Winnt\\Include\" -L\"%s\\Winnt\\lib_x64\\msc\" -lvisa64.lib", ...
getenv('VXIPNPPATH'), getenv('VXIPNPPATH'))
eval(cmd);
```

When run, the output of the command is:

```
>> mex main.cpp -I'C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\\Winnt\Include' -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\\Winnt\lib_x64\msc' -lvisa64.lib
g++: error: Files: No such file or directory
g++: error: (x86)\IVI: No such file or directory
g++: error: Foundation\VISA\\Winnt\lib_x64\msc: No such file or directory
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

I also tried to run the string directly from the command line:

```
mex main.cpp -I'C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\\Winnt\Include' -L'C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\\Winnt\lib_x64\msc' -lvisa64.lib
```

with the same result.
While the -I command appears to work well, why does the -L argument causes problems? What would be the right way to escape the path names with spaces?
Double quotes also won't work.

**EDIT**
Based on the answers, I am using mex() in its functional form, but the result is still the same:

```
vxipath = getenv('VXIPNPPATH');
params={};
params{1} = sprintf('-I%s', fullfile(vxipath, 'Winnt', 'Include'));
params{2} = sprintf('-L%s', fullfile(vxipath, 'Winnt', 'lib_x64', 'msc'));
params{3} = sprintf('-lvisa64.lib');

% replace \ with /
for i1=1:length(params)
  s = params{i1};
  s(s=='\') = '/';
  params{i1} = s;
end

params
mex("main.cpp", params{:});
```

Gives the output:

```
params =
{
  [1,1] = -IC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/Winnt/Include
  [1,2] = -LC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/Winnt/lib_x64/msc
  [1,3] = -lvisa64.lib
}

g++: error: Files: No such file or directory
g++: error: (x86)/IVI: No such file or directory
g++: error: Foundation/VISA/Winnt/lib_x64/msc: No such file or directory
warning: mkoctfile: building exited with failure status
```

Which is the same result as before. Additional observations are:

- '/' or '\' does not make a difference
- if I omit all parameters, I get a missing-include-file-error: OK
- if I omit the '-L' argument, I get a missing-lib-file-error: OK
- if I add the '-L' argument, I get the error shown above: It appears that the -L argument behaves differently than the -I argument.

I also tried it directly from the bash shell with the corresponding command with the same result.

Comment: `mex("main.cpp", params{:})` .  <-  You should use single quotes.

Comment: Please add the `-v` (verbose) flag to your `mex` command, so we can see what linker command is being executed. I think Octave might not be properly escaping the shell command.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thanks for -v. This is exactly the problem. Apparently mkoctfile is broken under windows. See the result in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkoctfile` does not escape the arguments properly if they contain spaces and it does not like backslashes in Octave's own paths. 
It creates the following two commands:

```
g++ -c -I/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include  -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include\octave-5.1.0\octave\.. -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include\octave-5.1.0\octave -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include   -fopenmp -g -O2   -I. "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\Winnt\Include"  -DMEX_DEBUG main.cpp -o C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\tmp/oct-u4r15I.o
g++ -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include\octave-5.1.0\octave\.. -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include\octave-5.1.0\octave -IC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\include   -fopenmp -g -O2 -shared -Wl,-rpath-link,/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/qt5/lib -Wl,--export-all-symbols  -o main.mex  C:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\tmp/oct-u4r15I.o  -lvisa64.lib  -LC:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\Winnt\lib_x64\msc -LC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\lib\octave\5.1.0 -LC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\lib -LC:\Octave\OCTAVE~1.0\\mingw64\lib\octave\5.1.0 -loctinterp -loctave  -Wl,-rpath-link,/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/qt5/lib -Wl,--export-all-symbols
```

When I change it to the following:

- replace `\` with `/`
- specify the library name without .lib extension
- escape `-LC:\Program Files...` to `"-LC:\Program Files..."`

```
g++ -c -I/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include  -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave/.. -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include   -fopenmp -g -O2   -I. "-IC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/Winnt/Include"  -DMEX_DEBUG main.cpp -o C:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0/tmp/oct-u4r15I.o  
g++ -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave/.. -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include/octave-5.1.0/octave -IC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/include   -fopenmp -g -O2 -shared -Wl,-rpath-link,/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/qt5/lib -Wl,--export-all-symbols  -o main.mex  C:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0/tmp/oct-u4r15I.o "-LC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA/Winnt/lib_x64/msc" -lvisa64 -LC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/lib/octave/5.1.0 -LC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/lib -LC:/Octave/OCTAVE~1.0//mingw64/lib/octave/5.1.0 -loctinterp -loctave  -Wl,-rpath-link,/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/release/mxe-octave-w64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/qt5/lib -Wl,--export-all-symbols
```

It will compile without error.

Comment: Maybe show the actual `mex` call, I'm assuming that you mean to include the `"` quotes inside the string as so: `'"-L..."'`?

Comment: The two g++ calls in the first box is what mex() generates. I needed to make the two changes in order to make it work.

Comment: Oh, so you're directly executing those `g++` calls in the shell?

Comment: Yes, in the bash shell which is installed together with octave.

Answer (score 1):

Replace backslashes with slashes and place each argument inside single quotes.

```
mex 'main.cpp' '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/Include' '-LC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/lib_x64/msc' '-lvisa64.lib'
```

or

```
mex ('main.cpp', '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/Include', '-LC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/lib_x64/msc', '-lvisa64.lib')
```

Comment: It seems like it doesn't make a difference. Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the how to fix it, as [rahnema1 already did that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57925874/7328782). But I'll show you how to simplify your code.

1. Do not use `eval`. [`eval` is evil](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).

   Instead of evaluating a string `function paramA paramB`, call `function` directly with string input arguments. `function paramA paramB` is translated by the interpreter to a call `function('paramA','paramB')`. But it is a lot easier to generate the latter form, and you get to avoid `eval` to boot:

   ```matlab
   params = {};
   params{1} = '-IC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/Include';
   params{2} = '-LC:/Program Files (x86)/IVI Foundation/VISA//Winnt/lib_x64/msc';
   params{2} = '-lvisa64.lib';
   mex('main.cpp', params{:});
   ```
2. Properly generate paths using `fullfile`. It adds `/` or `\` depending on which platform you're on, plus I find it easier to read:

   ```matlab
   include_path = fullfile(getenv('VXIPNPPATH'), 'Winnt', 'Include');
   params{1} = ['-I', include_path];
   ```

Comment: `fullfile` doesn't replace \ with /. Again needs extra work `include_path(include_path=='\')='/';`

Comment: @rahnema1: I wasn't aware of that. Is Octave picky about separators? I think MATLAB automatically translates forward slashes to backward slashes on Windows, but typically you'd use backward slashes on Windows when calling `mex`.

Comment: Octave is originally developed for non windows systems and port to windows is done by cross compiling so eventually we can see such incompatibilities.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't make a difference. Please see my edit above.